# 配列を昇順にソートしたとき，要素とソート前の番号を紐づけて保持したい

Tags: ruby

配列を昇順にソートしたとき，要素とソート前の番号を紐づけて保持したいです．

例えば，以下の用な処理を実現したいです．

```
arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
```

を昇順にソートして，何らかの方法で，「数値:ソート前の要素番号」へ．

```
arr_afterSort = [1:2, 3:3, 4:4, 5:0, 6:7, 7:5, 8:1, 9:6]
```

`Hash`を使う方法も考えたのですが，Keyは文字列，valueは数値でしか指定できないので私が実現したいことができません．
また，`.sort`で昇順にしても要素番号がわからなくなるかと思います．
あと，`require 'active_support'`，`require 'active_support/core_ext'`を使って配列を`.deep_dup`して，ソートした配列をdupした配列と同じ数字かを検索して要素番号を取得する，も考えたのですがスマートな手法ではなく，強引な感じがします．

どなたかご教授よろしくおねがいします．

Comment: 数値と順番のStructを配列にしたらどうでしょう？

Comment: `arr.map.with_index.sort` など。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これでどうでしょう

```
[5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6].each_with_index.sort
# => [[1, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 0], [6, 7], [7, 5], [8, 1], [9, 6]]
```

Hashが良ければto_hで

```
[5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6].each_with_index.sort.to_h
# => {1=>2, 3=>3, 4=>4, 5=>0, 6=>7, 7=>5, 8=>1, 9=>6}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
=> [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]

arr.each_with_index.sort_by { |n, _i| n }
=> [[1, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 0], [6, 7], [7, 5], [8, 1], [9, 6]]

arr.each_with_index.sort_by { |n, _i| n }.to_h
=> {1=>2, 3=>3, 4=>4, 5=>0, 6=>7, 7=>5, 8=>1, 9=>6}
```

でしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

質問に対応する回答はquiquiさんの方が的確ですが、私ならソート時のインデックスの配列だけ作ればいいと思うので、こうします。

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

arr = [5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]

index = arr.each_with_index.sort_by { |n, _i| n }.map { |_n, i| i }

print 'arr：'
pp arr
print 'index：'
pp index
puts "arrの最初の値：#{arr[0]}"
puts "arrのソート後の最初のindex：#{index[0]}"
puts "arrのソート後の最初の値：#{arr[index[0]]}"
```

結果は、

```
arr：[5, 8, 1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 6]
index：[2, 3, 4, 0, 7, 5, 1, 6]
arrの最初の値：5
arrのソート後の最初のindex：2
arrのソート後の最初の値：1
```

となると思います。